# Initializing a Nullable Type with Initobj Opcode in IL

Tags: c#, .net, struct, nullable, il

Why doesn't C# compiler simply call default implicit parameterless `.ctor` instead of `intobj` for `null` assigned nullable value types?

Lets say we have such as code:

```
Nullable<int> ex1 = new Nullable<int>();
Nullable<int> ex2 = null;
Nullable<int> ex3 = new Nullable<int>(10);
```

The IL output for these two lines look like this:

[image]

It only call `.ctor` for last statement and why cannot we have the an instance for two first  statements with zeroed fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why doesn't C# compiler simply call default implicit parameterless `.ctor` instead of `intobj` for null assigned nullable value types?

Because `Nullable<T>` (or any other value type) doesn't actually have a parameterless constructor. You can verify that by looking at it in a decompiler or using reflection (e.g. `typeof(Nullable<>).GetConstructors()`).

If you write `new T()` for some value type `T` in C#, it looks like it invokes a parameterless constructor (and the C# spec calls it a constructor too), but that's not what actually happens, because there is no parameterless `.ctor` method on value types.

Comment: Well you're very well right as my pictures shows that if there was one, it would be called in IL too but instead, it calls `intobj` instruction to initialize the value type even though I said `new Nullable<int>()`. I am marking your post as answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't C# compiler simply call default implicit parameterless `.ctor`

Because a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) like [`System.Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) cannot contain an explicit parameterless constructor; that's a requirement for defining a value type. Because one a value type cannot have an explicit parameterless constructor, `initobj` is the only method to default-construct a value type in CIL.

Comment: That's not shortcut, that's the only way to call it. And I'm not sure I would say it has no code, because it still has to initialize all fields.

Comment: No, it doesn't, because that's `initobj`'s job. I've edited my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `initobj` instruction initializes a value type and zeroes or nulls out its fields, as per [MSDN documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.initobj.aspx) Calling a default constructor *method* on top of that provides no additional value. Your last example passes in a value and therefore called a very specific constructor.